# How do I programmatically press control and right arrow key in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard

I need to programmatically press the control and the right arrow key simultaneously using the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) package.

I tried

```
keyboard.press("ctrl+right")
keyboard.press("ctrl+\033[C")
```

but both result in `ValueError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 351, in KeyboardSwitch
    return func(event)
  File "test2.py", line 37, in onKeyboardEvent
    keyboard.press("ctrl+\033[C")
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 362, in press
    resolved = self._resolve(key)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 556, in _resolve
    raise ValueError(key)
ValueError: ctrl+[C
```

How can I send a `Ctrl-Right Arrow` keystroke?

Comment: I tried running `keyboard.press("ctrl+right")` which worked (Windows) and you might forgot to release the key after pressing it. try `keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+right")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running `keyboard.press("ctrl+right")` which worked (Windows) and you might forgot to release the key after pressing it. try `keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+right")`